# Why echarts are not showing on I.E-11 version

Tags: vuejs2, internet-explorer-11, vue-cli-3, echarts

I had created a project using vuejs+Vue-CLI and integrated echarts in it. Echarts are working well in all browsers but when I open it in IE-11 version, page can't load and it shows following error:

> [object Error]{description: "Expected ')'", message: "Expected ')'", name: "SyntaxError", number: -2146827282, stack: "SyntaxError...", Symbol()_n.kyufm4c0tec: undefined, Symbol()_p.kyufm4c0tec: undefined, Symbol()_q.kyufm4c0tec: undefined, Symbol()_r.kyufm4c0tec: undefined, Symbol(Lang fallback)_m.kyufm4c0tec: undefined, Symbol(util.promisify.custom)_o.kyufm4c0tec: undefined}

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <ECharts :options="pie" style="width:300px; height:260px">
    </ECharts>
</template>

<script>
    import ECharts from "vue-echarts/components/ECharts.vue";
    import "echarts/lib/chart/pie";
    import "echarts/lib/component/title";

    export default {
        components: {
            ECharts
        },
        data() {
            return {
                pie: {
                    backgroundColor: "transparent",
                    tooltip: {
                        trigger: "item",
                        formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: "Product Sales",
                        type: "pie",
                        radius: ["50%", "70%"],
                        avoidLabelOverlap: false,
                        data: [{
                                value: 1,
                                name: "Product A"
                            },
                            {
                                value: 2,
                                name: "Product B"
                            },
                            {
                                value: 3,
                                name: "Product C"
                            }
                        ],
                        label: {
                            normal: {
                                show: false,
                                position: "center"
                            },
                            emphasis: {
                                show: true,
                                textStyle: {
                                    fontSize: "20",
                                    fontWeight: "bold"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        labelLine: {
                            normal: {
                                show: false
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

what's an issue in IE browser I also searched for the solution and tried it but did't get the result. 
Versions:

> echarts-4.1.0,
>   vue-echarts: 3.1.1

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: To narrow down the issue, can you just try to make a test with charts in your web page with IE 11? I assume that you are using github echarts library(There are 2 versions of echarts) If you try to open the echarts from their sites in IE than you will find that it is working properly. So it can be possible that any other thing cause this error in IE 11.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of vue-echarts-v3 does not inform it, but you have to add the echarts on your webpack (or any other bundler you are using) configuration as well.

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [
      resolve('src'),
      resolve('test'),
      resolve('node_modules/vue-echarts-v3/src'), // Their suggestion https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-echarts-v3
      resolve('node_modules/echarts/lib'), // Not suggested, but required as well
    ]
  },
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @Clerston but I am using package vue-echarts not vue-echarts-v3